# Not Creating Database using Entity Framework code first Approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am  just try to creating Database using entity Framework5.0 code first Approach In Mvc web Application when i execute code it execute fine but not creating database.if i send input values from views then Database is created???
I Want to know whats the mechanism behind this entity frame work code Approach
Can any one Help to find out the mechanism of entity frame work.

Comment: try reading this first [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do know it didn't create the database?
If everything works fine, I mean no errors, the database should be created already.

My guess is you didn't specify the connection string which caused the database created in SQL Express.

Comment: first time when i execute the code then code do not show any error and execute fine and show the signup view
when i finish the execution and check it does not make database. if i run again and provide the values in signup form then it create database. why this is odd behviour? it should create database when i execute and browse the page

Comment: Em providing conection String it works fine but its odd behaviour is distrubing me.

Comment: It will create database when you first access the database. I'm sure the signup httpget action doesn't access the database.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the wrong database creation strategy

Comment: What kind of Wrong Strategy???
i have two basic classes of userLogin ,and User sign up class
and anther class is UserContext class that is inherit from DbContext class and to create a databse table i use 
'public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }'
method for constr
'public OnlineShopContext()
                :base("Name=Constr3")
      {
      }'

Comment: And constr is 
' <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="Constr3" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EShop1;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
'

Comment: I'm sorry, but what database creation strategies for code first are is something google can easily answer.